# forfiles *.something mask does not filter output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a basic forfiles command, but no matter what mask I use it always simply prints the whole content of the directory. Not filtered for *.bat  no "is a batch file", just a simple list off all files in C:\
I'm working on a winXPproffesional. What could be the cause?

```
forfiles /p c:\ /s /m *.bat /c "cmd /c echo @file is a batch file"
```

Comment: It works for me on Vista. What version of Windows are you using? BTW, you might want to use `@PATH` instead of `@FILE` when you use the /S option.

Comment: Win XP Prof. Vers2002 SP3  Same output when using @path.... I don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow this version uses a different syntax:

```
FORFILES -pc:\ -s -m*.BAT -c"CMD /C Echo @file is a batch file"
```

works!

Comment: +1 Interesting. That syntax does not work on Vista. The space between the option and the value is required on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

The command should work.

Maybe you have a FORFILES.BAT, FORFILES.CMD or bogus copy of FORFILES.EXE in either your current directory or another directory that happens to be in your PATH.

Try running this command from the command line to verify that the correct FORFILES.EXE is executing.

```
for %F in (forfiles.exe forfiles.bat forfiles.cmd) do @echo %~$path:F
```

If that is not the problem, then it looks to me like you have a bugged version of FORFILES.

Try using one option at a time to see which, if any of the options work

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, [there's no `forfiles` in Windows XP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) but there *is* one [in Windows 2003 Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778084%28WS.10%29.aspx), with the [syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755872%28WS.10%29.aspx) as in your question.

Windows 2000 *did* have the tool, but only in the form of a resource kit, which had to be downloaded separately. For some reason, the [corresponding Technet article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229) doesn't list `forfiles` as part of the kit, although, as can be derived from [this](http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm) and [this article](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/reskit/reskit2000/), it must have been there initially. Maybe the guys at Microsoft decided to stop distributing the older version to avoid possible confusion with the newer one.

And yes, it seems like your `forfiles` copy is the older version, which does have a slightly different syntax, as explained [in this post](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080324215719AAeNAvP).